# Cant run google cloudprint as daemon

Tags: python, linux, debian, google-cloud-print

I am having som trouble when installing the Google Cloudprint python script.

```
holmen@filserver:~/tmp$ sudo service cloudprint start
Starting Google Cloud Print: daemon module required for -d
        yum install python-daemon, or apt-get install python-daemon, or pip install python-daemon
holmen@filserver:~/tmp$ sudo apt-get install python-daemon
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python-daemon is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Even though i have installed the python-daemon i gives me an error.

My init-d script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# /etc/rc.d/cloudprint
# Description: Starts the Google Cloud Print script on startup
# ----------------
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: Cloud-Print
# Required-Start: $cups $network $local_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Description: Start Google Cloud Print
### END INIT INFO

USER="holmen"
PIDFILE="/var/run/cloudprint/pid"

case $1 in
        start)
                echo -n "Starting Google Cloud Print: "
                sudo -u $USER cloudprint -d -p $PIDFILE
        ;;
        stop)
                echo -n "Stopping Google Cloud Print: "
                killall cloudprint
        ;;
        restart)
                echo -n "Restarting Google Cloud Print: "
                killall cloudprint
                sudo -u $USER cloudprint -d -p $PIDFILE
        ;;
        *)
                echo "Usage: cloudprint {start|stop|restart}"
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and solved it by uninstalling the daemon module and installing the pacakge python-daemon instead, i.e. on my debian system:

```
pip uninstall daemon
apt-get install python-daemon
```